# How to move tip tag on Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to move the "tip" tag to revision 272 on the following graph. Is it possible without commiting on that head?

```
o  changeset:   273:40cf2237a3d5
|  bookmark:    push-notification
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      271:3640ade1df38
|  user:        xxxxxxxxx <xxxxx@zzzz.com>
|  date:        Mon May 12 16:11:01 2014 -0300
|  summary:     Lorem
|
| @  changeset:   272:70f0a3f3b74a
| |  parent:      269:b125e398bd69
| |  user:        yyyyyyyy <yyyyyyy@zzzzz.com>
| |  date:        Fri May 09 17:58:35 2014 -0300
| |  summary:     Ipsum
| |
o |  changeset:   271:3640ade1df38
| |  user:        yyyyyyyy <yyyyyyy@zzzzz.com>
| |  date:        Fri May 09 17:58:35 2014 -0300
| |  summary:     Dolor
| |
o |  changeset:   270:d064bf9ffad6
| |  parent:      268:01563b587c71
| |  user:        xxxxxxxxx <xxxxx@zzzz.com>
| |  date:        Fri May 09 11:00:47 2014 -0300
| |  summary:     Sit
| |
| o  changeset:   269:b125e398bd69
| |  parent:      267:602390d3eeb1
| |  user:        xxxxxxxxx <xxxxx@zzzz.com>
| |  date:        Fri May 09 08:13:06 2014 -0300
| |  summary:     Amet
| |
o |  changeset:   268:01563b587c71
|/   user:        xxxxxxxxx <xxxxx@zzzz.com>
|    date:        Tue May 06 17:47:32 2014 -0300
|    summary:     Consectur
|
o  changeset:   267:602390d3eeb1
|  user:        yyyyyyyy <yyyyyyy@zzzzz.com>
|  date:        Fri May 02 14:24:29 2014 -0300
|  summary:     Abc
|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. `tip` is simply "most recent commit". If you want the branch with the head at 272, you should give it another bookmark. It's definitely advisable to just ignore `tip` completely.

Answer (score 2):

As @moswald said, it is not possible to change the `tip` in itself, as it is pointing to the *tipmost* changeset of ***your*** repository. As such, `tip` is not necessarily a good reference to use.

However, there is something that you can do, to change the tip here. This has no real value, but I explain it for *theoretical* reasons only. The solution to your problem, without doing any other commit on the other branch, is to push (for backup, e.g. you need a cloned or main repo), strip and re-pull the commit you want as `tip`.

```
hg push  -r 70f0a3f3b74a
hg strip -r 70f0a3f3b74a
hg pull  -r 70f0a3f3b74a
```

Then, simply update again to the same changeset, if needed, and you can either do

```
hg update -r 70f0a3f3b74a
```

Or...

```
hg update -r tip
```